# why is the gain of ad620 not responding to the change in( Rg), the gain resistor?

Tags: biopotential

I am building an ECG sensor based on the AD620 instrumentation amplifier.For the purposes of testing , i have built a simple AD620 circuit with pin 2(-) and pin 3(+) connected to a 2.82mV(peak to peak) sinusoidal signal generator. pin 7(+Vs) is connected to +4.5,pin 4(-Vs) is connected to -4.5. a 33k Ohm resistor is connected between pin 1 and pin 8 which theoretically should give a gain of around 2.5. Pin 5(Vref) is grounded and pin 6(output) is connected to an oscilloscope with ac coupling. 
1)My first problem is the signal on the scope is 282mV peak to peak which implies a gain of 100, how can this be explained and solved?
2) if I change the gain resitor from 33k, to 37.7k, to 70.3k, I still get the same output.
3)if I change the input signal from 2.82mV peak to peak to 0.91mV I stil get the same output swing, however if i switch off the signal generator the output goes to zero.
I have also tried to connect 33k resitors between each input and the ground but the result is the same.[image: circuit diagram]

Comment: Measure the INPUT waveform with your scope to make sure your numbers make sense.  In particular, pay attention to the channel probe settings and any impedance switches on the probe.

Comment: Also, measure your resistor.

Comment: As Scott says, make sure your input voltage from the function generator is actually that low, some function generators can't directly produce signals that small.

Comment: @ScottSeidman_, The input signal is too small for the scope to properly pick I think, I have tried to connect it to the scope but it is displayed superimposed on noise which makes it really difficult to distinguish it. I am new to the oscilloscope, so you can help with a better way of using it. the signal generator i am using is for biomedical purposes,it produces a signal in the range of 0-2.82mV peak to peak.

Comment: If you can't see 2.8mV, you'll probably have issues with 2.8mVx2.5 -- I recommended you do this just to confirm that you're not having issues with a scope or probe setup.  Have you measured your resistor?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany_, i have tried a different signal generator feeding approx 18mV peak to peak to the amplifier which gave me approx 1.82v at the output.

Comment: The only things I can think of, assuming all your scope settings are correct, are to MEASURE YOUR RESISTOR (!!!!) and to CONFIRM THAT YOU ARE USING AN AD620 by checking the number on the chip.

Comment: @ScottSeidman_,I take that, 2.5x2.8mV is maybe too close to 2.8mV, the resistor is fine I have measured it, I have tried a 4.7k resistor, it is giving me the same result. could it be possibly my breadboard?

Comment: @ScottSeidman_the chip is written AD620N on top.

Comment: @ScottSeidman_,what do you mean by impedance switches on the probe?

Comment: You've got the 'scope gain for one channel set as a x10 probe.  (a guess)

Comment: That's why I'd like you to measure the input signal using the SAME PROBE on the SAME CHANNEL.

Comment: @ScottSeidman-well, the circuit worked,it was a problem of the ad620 chip which was fault.

Comment: however,on the same project, I am having a problem in taping the ecg signal from the human body. the amplifier is working well when I connect it to a signal generator,amplifying signals as small as 10uV. however, when i connect the eletrodes to the human body,I get a very small sine wave at 50Hz, 4mV peak to peak. what might be the problem.